# Eclipse Helios CDT: ignore build directory

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

We use Eclipse Helios CDT for development. We use cmake as build system, build dirs are typically called build-* inside the project directory.

How do I get the indexer and the refactoring tool to ignore the build directories?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Exclude these build dirs from project tree by adding [Resource filters](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/resourcefilters.htm). Add **Exclude All** resource filter type to root folder of your project. You can also use regular expressions if needed.